# Can you help identify this bird in Louisville Kentucky?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

[This bird shows up in my back yard every night.  It is calling and sometimes I hear a bird in the distance calling back.  I think its an owl but I haven't seen it yet.  Any ideas what it is?](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HRrj90PTma55M_bvQR6_69mLG80H5Dqr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me that sounds like the distinctive "who cooks for you" call of the [Barred owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barred_owl).

Compare with the recordings available from the [Audubon Society](https://www.audubon.org/field-guide/bird/barred-owl), [Cornell's All About Birds](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Barred_Owl/sounds), and many others such as this [YouTube video from a Cornell Lab Bird Cam of a Barred owl calling from its nest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayDzQrV8wss).

Comment: That it!  Thanks.  Now got to find a way to get a camera on this bird...

Comment: My Gravitar is from one we observed that was hunting around mid-day so this is definitely possible. Looking for owl pellets around largish trees in your neighborhood may help you identify where it roosts or nests.

Comment: @tyersome I agree that this is definitively a barred owl. Very distinct call. As my wife always says when I imitate the call: "*you* do!!" :p